# menu with hierarchical data 

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a Hierarchical Table for Categories in this form `NodeID` `ParentID` `NodeName`

Following is the code i am using generate `ASP.NET MENU ITEMS` and bind it to `MENU CONTROL`

```
Private Sub displayMenu()
        Using con As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("HagglerEntLibConStr").ConnectionString)
            Using sql As New SqlCommand("Select NodeID,ParentID,NodeName FROM Nodes", con)
                con.Open()
                Dim r As SqlDataReader = sql.ExecuteReader 'stored procedure that returns the above SqlDataReader
                Dim tempMaster As New MenuItem()
                Dim bagMaster(700) As MenuItem
                Dim j As Integer = 0
                Do While r.Read()
                    tempMaster.Value = r("NodeID").ToString()
                    tempMaster.ToolTip = r("ParentID").ToString()
                    tempMaster.Text = r("NodeName").ToString()
                    tempMaster.NavigateUrl = ""
                    bagMaster(j) = tempMaster
                    j += 1
                    tempMaster = New MenuItem()
                Loop
                r.Close()
                Menu1.Items.Clear()
                For i As Integer = 0 To j - 1
                    If i = 0 Then
                        Menu1.Items.Add(bagMaster(i))
                    Else
                        For x As Integer = 0 To j - 1
                            If bagMaster(i).ToolTip = bagMaster(x).Value Then
                                Dim c As MenuItem = bagMaster(x)
                                'you can change the tool tip here if you want
                                c.ChildItems.Add(bagMaster(i))
                            End If
                        Next x
                    End If
                Next i
                'Menu1.Items.RemoveAt(0)

            End Using

        End Using

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        displayMenu()
    End Sub
```

Everything works fine ...but the main disadvantage with this approach is that the `Menu CONTROL` creates `HTML TABLES`...i have around 1000 rows in the table..this creates a multi level menu ...which adds a lot of `HTML Tables` in the page and increases the page load time drastically...how do i tackle this issue?? This is the way the menu populates.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with the [RenderingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.renderingmode.aspx) property?

Values:

- Default. (This is the default value). The rendering mode depends on the [RenderingCompatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.renderingcompatibility.aspx) control property, if this setting is set to *3.5*, the default rendering is a `table`, if this value is *4.0*, the default rendering mode is a list `ul`. You can change this setting globally in the web.config file:

  ```
  <system.web>
      <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  ```
- Table. Renders as a table
- List. Renders as a list

### Update 1

Since you are using the .Net Framework 3.5, probably the best way to accomplish this is to use [Control Adapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.adapters.controladapter.aspx)

Basically the adapters work on a specific control, and in the adapter you can update the rendering of the target control, in this case the `Menu` control

I have not created a control adapter, so I cannot give you further information other than pointing you in the right direction, googling I found this article which seems promising:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx

Comment: Is this property available in Visual Studio 2008?? I mean .NET 3.5?

Comment: i am using 3.5...any suggestion?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time...really appretiate it.